# How to delete contents of an HTML tag in Emacs

Tags: html, vim, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor

Vim has an awesome feature that allows users to delete contents of tags, within quotation marks, etc. For example, in the following situation:

```
<h1>  Cursor is here -> █ <- :)  </h1>
```

one can type <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> (“delete in tag”) to delete the contents of the `<h1>` HTML tag.

There are also other shortcuts, for example:

- <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>(</kbd> to delete contents in parentheses `()`
- <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> to delete contents in double quotes `""`.
- <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> to delete contents in single quotes `''`.

Does anything like this exist for Emacs?

I'm aware of `zap-to-char` and nXhtml's `sgml-delete-tag`, but they don't quite do what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How's this code work for you?

```
(defun sgml-delete-tagged-text ()
  "delete text between the tags that contain the current point"
  (interactive)
  (let ((b (point)))
    (sgml-skip-tag-backward 1)
    (when (not (eq b (point)))
      ;; moved somewhere, should be at front of a tag now
      (save-excursion 
        (forward-sexp 1)
        (setq b (point)))
      (sgml-skip-tag-forward 1)
      (backward-sexp 1)
      (delete-region b (point)))))
```